# PHP and SQLite - Issue with string including space

Tags: php, sqlite, get

I'm trying to make a website to access a SQLite database and retrieve info on different people. However, I'm having some problems. Here's my code for my index page.

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('people.db');
$results = $db->query('select FirstName,LastName from People');
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
            echo '<div class="person"><p class="name"><a href="lookup.php?first=" .
                urlencode($row['FirstName']) . '&last=' . urlencode($row['LastName']) . '">' .
                $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['LastName'] . '</a></p></div>;
        ?>
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the lookup.php code:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('people.db');
$first = urldecode($_GET['first']);
$last = urldecode($_GET['last']);
$results = $db->query('select * from People where FirstName="' . $first . '" and LastName="' . $last . '"');
$row = $results->fetchArray();
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="person">
            Name: <?php echo $row['FirstName'] ?><br/>
            Last Name: <?php echo $row['LastName'] ?><br/>
            Age: <?php echo $row['Age'] ?><br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click on a person's name on the index page whose FirstName is "Denzil" and LastName is "Ezras", it works fine. lookup.php displays his FirstName, LastName, and Age. However, I run into problems when a person's first or last name has a space in it. For instance, a person whose FirstName is "James" and LastName is "De Jongh", lookup.php will show no FirstName, LastName, or Age. The URL for this page comes up as:

```
http://localhost/lookup.php?first=James&last=De+Jongh
```

I have tried using var_export in PHP to take a look at $first and $last, and they seem in order. When I copy and paste them into sqlite3.exe, it comes up with the proper values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
as i can see from the url, instead of displaying the space as %20 it display it as + 
this will convert any spaces to %20 which is acceptable by the url.

```
$last = str_replace(' ', '%20', $last);
```

or you can simply use

```
rawurlencode($lastName);
```

Comment: +1 for `rawurlencode`. -1 for `str_replace`: what about other characters?

Comment: simply here i'm replacing the url through GET . this code will be executed in the other script when he gets the url, simply just replaces the space with %20 , u can still up vote the answer tho :p

Comment: Does urldecode still work properly or will I have to use rawurldecode to decode the input?